# The number of students in this group who are enrolled in MATH 101 or ENG 101

Tags: discrete-mathematics, multisets

Suppose in a group of 23 students 15 are enrolled in MATH 101, and 12 are enrolled in ENG 101. If there are 5 students in this group who are not enrolled in any of these two classes, find

a) The number of students in this group who are enrolled in MATH 101 or ENG 101: Answer = ________

b) The number of students in this group who are enrolled in both MATH 101 and ENG 101: Answer = _______

c) The number of students in this group who are enrolled in exactly one of the two classes: Answer =

Comment: Lets define some sets 1) $U$ is the set of the universe or the all the students in the group. 2) $M$ is the set of the students in Math101 3) $E$ is the set of students in Eng101.  We don't really care about each person in this situation. What we are conserned about is the amount of people or the Cardinality of sets. So Question time do you know about unions and intersections of sets?

Comment: Yes sir I about it. But I dont know the answer to this

Comment: You should be able to get part (a) just by reading the question and one subtraction. To help you get part (b), first answer this: (a+) how many of the students in part (a) are not enrolled in Math 101?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M = \{students\ enrolled\ in\ MTH101\}$ and $E = \{students\ enrolled \ in \ ENG101\}$

a) total - not enrolled in any course i.e 
    $23-5 =18$

b) $M\cup E = M + E - M\cap E$
    so , 18 = 15 + 12 - $M\cap E$

```
  you need
```

$ M\cap E $

c) it's just $M - M\cap E$

and $E - E\cap M$